# storyboard: table view appearing behind navigation bar

Tags: ios, xcode

As per the picture below, part of the TableView is appearing behind the Navigation Bar.

I had been ignoring it, thinking it was just the way the storyboard drew things because it looks ok in the app.  But it can be problematic - sometimes, to select the cell behind the Navigation Bar, one needs to use the Document Outline.

Is that just how it goes?  Or is there a way to get Xcode to draw things properly?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like you have selected a translucent navigation bar which will not push down other subviews. Try using the standard or black navigation bar. It probably looks fine in the app because your navigation controller using the non-translucent bar.

Comment: That was it!  While it now looks exactly like it should - both on the device and in Xcode - I can imagine wanting a background image to show through and therefore wanting the nav bar to be translucent but also to have the tableviews appear below the bar.  Hmm.

Comment: In that case you could just manually adjust the table view frame to be under the navigation bar (and put a UIImageView under the navigation bar for example).

Comment: Something else is causing the same problem for me